# Are they ways to overcome the limitation with DI where I need constructor arguments when I wanted to simply new up an element or create it with XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dependency-injection

I am using:

`Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` version 5.0.1 nuget package, and I am creating a class called `ArrowGrid` that creates some graphic elements.

I would like to call the class like this in C# and possibly XAML:

```
var arrowGrid = new ArrowGrid();

<ArrowGrid />
```

However `ArrowGrid` needs a service:

```
public class ArrowGrid : BaseGrid
{
    private readonly IGraphicsService _graphicsService;
    public ArrowGrid(IGraphicsService graphicsService)
    {
        _graphicsService = graphicsService;
        var fr         = _graphicsService.GetFrameWithArrow();
        Children.Add(fr, 3, 0);
    }
}
```

Now I have a problem as `new ArrowGrid()` will give me an error saying there is no default constructor with no arguments so I had an idea to do this:

```
public class ArrowGrid : BaseGrid
{
    private readonly IGraphicsService _graphicsService;
    public ArrowGrid()
    {
        _graphicsService = Startup.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<GraphicsService>();
        var fr         = _graphicsService.GetFrameWithArrow();
        Children.Add(fr, 3, 0);
    }
}
```

But from what I read see below it's always suggested to use constructor arguments:

> Of course, you typically shouldn't be using the IServiceProvider
> directly in your code at all. Instead, you should be using standard
> constructor injection, and letting the framework worry about using
> IServiceProvider behind the scenes.

Is it just with the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` that this is a problem?  How about with other DI solutions? I don't know about those and would appreciate advice as to if they offer more capabilities.  Also is my idea the correct way to overcome this problem? Note that in this case the `graphicsService` is a very simple service that I would never need to replace when doing testing.

Here's what I am currently doing:

```
var abc = new ArrowGrid
{
   Text1               = "Talk to us",
   TapCommandParam     = "Home/FBPage",
   IconSource          = Const.IconSource.CardOptions,
};
```

Here I believe is the suggestion:

```
var abc = Startup.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ArrowGrid>();
abc.Text1 = "Talk to us";
abc.TapCommandParam = "Home/FBPage";
abc.IconSource = Const.IconSource.CardOptions;
```

Comment: Instead of doing `new`, ask DI Container to resolve the instance for you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I have added to the question some lines based on your suggestion.  Can you confirm that you think this is the way that I should be doing this.  I guess the only problem for me is that if I do it this way then I cannot use XAML to instantiate the object any more as that object must be created with the DI.

Comment: Using `ServiceProvider` directly is an anti-pattern. Now, you've also tightly coupled `MyTestClass` with `Startup`. Both defeat the purpose of DI. If you need a dependency, request it externally and pass it in. Otherwise rethink your design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Startup.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ArrowGrid>()` looks fine for me but there's a better way to do that. DI Container allows you to be lazy and not create anything yourself either with `new`, or with DI Container imperatively.

Consider this example. Hope the class where you writing the code is registered in the `ServiceCollection`.

```cs
public class MyTestClass
{
    public MyTestClass()
    {
        var abc = Startup.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ArrowGrid>();
        abc.Text1 = "Talk to us";
        abc.TapCommandParam = "Home/FBPage";
        abc.IconSource = Const.IconSource.CardOptions;
    }
}
```

Can be easily replaced with DI version of the same.

```cs
public class MyTestClass
{
    public MyTestClass(ArrowGrid abc)
    {
        abc.Text1 = "Talk to us";
        abc.TapCommandParam = "Home/FBPage";
        abc.IconSource = Const.IconSource.CardOptions;
    }
}
```

That's the sense of Composition Root of your App where the classes are registered.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer.  One other small question I have, is what if I needed two ArrowGrids in my one file.  For example var arrowGrid1 = new ArrowGrid(); and var arrowGrid2 = new ArrowGrid();  Do you have any suggestions on how I could do that?

Comment: @RichardA `public MyTestClass(ArrowGrid abc, ArrowGrid def)`? :)

Comment: @aepot sorry meant to comment on OP